# XML declaration in middle of XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement to send a xml message from XSLT.

But when i am giving xml declaration for my message in middle of XSLT. It is throwing error because, it is not expecting this in middle of page. How can i send my xml message with xml declaration through XSL?

Any inputs are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `<xsl:output>` tag ([XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output), [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#serialization)) at the top level of your stylesheet to construct the XML declaration for the output, for example:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" />
```

would put a declaration of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

at the top of the output document.